# Cannot acces a closed stream error in .Net Maui

Tags: xaml, maui

I built myself a camera control in .NET Maui, which adds the ImageSources to a List (also tried an ObservableCollection) that is located in the ImageSourceCollectionClass:

```
namespace CargoCapture.Services
{
    public partial class ImageSourceCollectionClass : ObservableObject
    {
        private static ImageSourceCollectionClass _instance;

        public static ImageSourceCollectionClass Instance => _instance ??= new ImageSourceCollectionClass();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private List<ImageSource> imageSourceCollection = new List<ImageSource>();
    }
}
```

I then want to continue to a photo preview which just takes the ImageSources and puts them into a List in the ViewModel:

```
public partial class ImageCollectionVM : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<ImageSource> imageSourceCollection = new List<ImageSource>();

    public ImageCollectionVM()
    {
        var imageCollectionClass = ImageSourceCollectionClass.Instance;

        ImageSourceCollection = imageCollectionClass.ImageSourceCollection;
        
    }
}
```

This all works just fine, the Lists are never null and also have the correct format.
But when I bind that List to the Preview, the App crashes and give me a error saying "Cannon access closed Stream":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CargoCapture.View.ImageCollectionView"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2022/xaml/maui"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:CargoCapture.ViewModel"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             BackgroundColor="#f7f7f7">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:ImageCollectionVM />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSourceCollection}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

After experimenting a bit I discoverd a XAML code that at least doenst crash the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CargoCapture.View.ImageCollectionView"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2022/xaml/maui"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:CargoCapture.ViewModel"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             BackgroundColor="#f7f7f7">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:ImageCollectionVM />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSourceCollection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This causes another problem, instead of displaying an actual Image I only get "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StreamImageSource" displayed as a string (why is it a StreamImageSource instead of a ImageSource now?).

I did try to use a CarouselView instead of the ListView/CollectionView and also changed the Image control for an Imagebutton, which I successfully used on the CameraControl to display the last taken image so I dont think its a problem with my camera control.

Does anybody know a solution for either one of my prolems?
Is my approach with the ImageSourceCollection class correct or is there another, better way?

Answer (score 0):

We usually get the path of the image and then show it.

You can use [Media picker for photos and videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) to take or pick photos.

Please refer to the following code :

```
public class MediaPickerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    string photoPath;

    bool showPhoto;
    
   // add Images to save the path of images
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Images { get; set; }


    public MediaPickerViewModel()
    {
        PickPhotoCommand = new Command(DoPickPhoto);
        CapturePhotoCommand = new Command(DoCapturePhoto, () => MediaPicker.IsCaptureSupported);


        Images = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    }

    public ICommand PickPhotoCommand { get; }

    public ICommand CapturePhotoCommand { get; }


    public bool ShowPhoto
    {
        get => showPhoto;
        set => SetProperty(ref showPhoto, value);
    }

    public string PhotoPath
    {
        get => photoPath;
        set => SetProperty(ref photoPath, value);
    }

    async void DoPickPhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();

            await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);

            Console.WriteLine($"PickPhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"PickPhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    async void DoCapturePhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

            await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);

            Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


    async void DoCaptureVideo()
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync();

            await LoadVideoAsync(photo);

            Console.WriteLine($"CaptureVideoAsync COMPLETED: {VideoPath}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CaptureVideoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
    {
        // canceled
        if (photo == null)
        {
            PhotoPath = null;
            return;
        }

        // save the file into local storage
        var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
        }

        PhotoPath = newFile;

        //add image to list

        Images.Add(new Item { ImageUrl = PhotoPath ,Name = "image " + Images.Count +1});

        ShowVideo = false;
        ShowPhoto = false;


        //
    }



    public override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        PhotoPath = null;
        VideoPath = null;

        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note:

You can check the official sample here: [PlatformIntegrationDemos](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/PlatformIntegration/PlatformIntegrationDemos).